# Codeigniter validate checkbox group

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, forms

I have this html code that I want to validate using the Codeigniter `Form_Validation` class :

```
<form id="thread" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkAllAuto" id="checkAll" onclick="CheckAll(this.id)" /><?php echo __t($dir_lang,'request_select_all');?> 
    <br />
    <?php foreach ($threads as $thread): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" class="threads" name="option[]" value="<?php echo $thread['th_id']; ?>" /> <?php echo $thread['th_title']; ?> <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mom" /> <?php echo __t($dir_lang,'request_send');?> 
    <br />
    <select name="cat">
        <?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $cat['title']; ?> </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br /><input type="submit" value="<?php echo __t($dir_lang,'submit');?> " /><br>
</form>
```

I'm trying to validate the fist group of the check box by using `Form_Validation`

```
if ($this->input->isMethodPost())
{
    $this->tplData['showMess'] = true;
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<h3>', '</h3>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('options[]','options', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->tplData['showError'] = true;
        $this->tplData['mess'] = array(validation_errors());
    }else{ 
        // my work
    }
}
```

It gives required filed message but even if I choose one or all the checkbox it still gives the required message.

Comment: is there any one can help me ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your code you set `options[]` as your name in `set_rules`:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('options[]','options', 'required');
```

while on your HTML your checkbox name is `option[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" class="threads" name="option[]" value="<?php echo $thread['th_id']; ?>" />
```

Fix this and tell me what the error is and i'll update my answer

Comment: for me it only worked if I use the following:
$this->form_validation->set_rules('option[]','option[]', 'required');

<input type="checkbox" class="threads" name="option[]" value="<?php echo $thread['th_id']; ?>" />

Comment: This is for CodeIgniter 3.1.2